# How to loading appconfig to project StringBoot from AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I want to external config file spring-boot application. Config file I saved in Amazon S3. how to code to load config in the project? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is an open request to enable S3 as a backend store for Spring Cloud Config here https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/654. And there is an attempt to do so by boilerplate code here https://github.com/mwnorman/spring-cloud-config-server-s3

Copying the relevant parts here

> it depends on spring-cloud-config-server and aws-java-sdk-s3 and has
>   an auto-config class in META-INF/spring.factories:
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=\
>   org.springframework.cloud.config.s3.CloudConfigS3AutoConfiguration
>   which looks like
>
> ```
> @Configuration
> @ConditionalOnBean(CloudConfigS3Configuration.Marker.class)
> @EnableConfigurationProperties(CloudConfigS3Properties.class)
> @Import({S3EnvironmentRepositoryConfiguration.class})
> public class CloudConfigS3AutoConfiguration {}
> ```
>
> The S3EnvironmentRepositoryConfiguration class looks like
>
> ```
> @Configuration
> public class S3EnvironmentRepositoryConfiguration {
>     @Autowired
>     protected ConfigurableEnvironment environment;
>     @Autowired
>     protected CloudConfigS3Properties s3Properties;
>     @Bean
>     @Primary
>     public EnvironmentRepository environmentRepository() {
>         return new S3EnvironmentRepository(environment, s3Properties);
>     }
>     @Bean
>     public CloudConfigS3Properties buildCloudConfigS3Properties() {
>         return new CloudConfigS3Properties();
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> A simple client:
>
> ```
> @SpringBootApplication(
>     //Hmm I think I shouldn't have to do this ... haven't figured it out yet
>     exclude = {
>         org.springframework.cloud.config.server.config.ConfigServerAutoConfiguration.class
>     }
> )
> @EnableS3CloudConfig
> public class Client {
>
>     public static void main(String[] args) {
>         ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext = new SpringApplicationBuilder(Client.class)
>             .web(false)
>             .run(args)
>         ;
>         applicationContext.getEnvironment().getProperty("foo.bar");
>     }
> }
> ```

More here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/654#issuecomment-321004867

Comment: I am a newbie.  I'm trying but not running. You can send me an example,

Comment: Everyone help me

Comment: @DuyKhoa What have you tried so far, and what issue are you facing exactly? Can you give the url to your github